# Get a list of child ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Helllo, I have a div with the following structure:

```
<div id = 'outside'>
    <div id = 'inside1'>
        <img id = 'image1' src='some.png'>
    </div>
    <div id = 'inside2'>
        <img id = 'image2' src='some2.png'>
    </div>
    ...
</div
```

Contents of the outside div are generated automatically from preloaded elements, and I want to transfer it's structure to php. Passing the whole html() content is quite heavy.

How can I using js or Jquery save only the id's of child divs and images in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `id`s:

```
var allIds = $('#outside').find('[id]').map(function(){ return this.id; }).get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9ddXF/1/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [Has-attribute (`'[attribute]'`)selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find('*')` to get all the `descendants` inside the source element, Then use `.each` to traverse all those elements , get the elements `id` accordingly  and store that in an `array`.

Try,

```
var xIds = [];

$('#outside').find('*').each(function(){
   xIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LZAfq/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.map

```
var arr = $.map($('#outside').children(), function(el) {
    var o = {};
    o[el.id] = $.map($('img', el), function(el2) {return el2.id;});
    return o;
});

// returns an array of objects where the parents are keys
// and the values are arrays of the images inside
// [
//   {
//     "inside1": [
//       "image1"
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     "inside2": [
//       "image2"
//     ]
//   }
// ]
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6EJ2V/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS method for placing the IDs of all children of the "outside" div into a "childrenIDs" array:

```
var children = document.getElementById('outside').children;
var childrenIDs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    childrenIDs.push(children[i].id);
}
```